# Regression with spline under constraints

Tags: r, spline

I am looking for a way to interpolate data with splines but force the values and the derivatives at the end points. This is my data:

```
library(tidyverse)
data <- tibble(x = 0:600, y = pnorm((-300:300)/100)+(runif(0:600)-0.5)/20)
# add noise
data$y[1] <- 0.35
data$y[2] <- 0.25
ggplot(data, aes(x = x, y = y)) + geom_point()
```

Now let's fit this data with a spline

```
fit <- lm(formula = y ~ splines::ns(x, 5),
          data = data)
data$y_new <- predict.lm(fit)
ggplot(data, aes(x = x, y = y_new)) + geom_point(aes(y = y), alpha = 0.5) + 
geom_point(color = 'red')
```

[image]

As you can see, because of the noise, there is a slight upward curvature remaining in the spline on the left hand side (and a downward curvature on the right hand side).

I want to force the value of the spline to be 0 and the derivative of the spline to be 0 (horizontal) when x = 0. So far I haven't been able to do this.

I've also tried to play with the Boundary.knots argument, but that didn't help me either.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way to do it

```
spline <- with(data, cobs::cobs(x, y, pointwise=rbind(c(0,min(x),0),c(0,max(x),1))))
data$y_new <- predict(spline, z = data$x)[,2]
ggplot(data, aes(x = x, y = y_new)) + 
  geom_point(aes(y = y), alpha = 0.5) + 
  geom_point(color = 'red')
```

[image]

([via](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/29400/spline-fitting-in-r-how-to-force-passing-two-data-points))

Comment: That doesn't completely tackle the derivative part of the question, but apparently that is also possible with cobs

Comment: @takje Hm force the prediction for the 2nd x value to be zero, too?

Comment: This could lead to extreem interpolations, or am I wrong. It could still do whatever it would want between x1 and x2. It shouldn't necessarily be a straight line.

Comment: Unfortunately the cobs splines only go until the second order. You can fix their first order derivatives with pointwise = c(2,xi,yi) where the 2 indicates that it is the second order, xi is the x value of the point in which you want to fix the derivative and yi is the value of the derivative. Thank you for the answer, but unfortunately it doesn't completely answer my question.